# Execute two different queries in one transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute two insert queries in one `Statement`, putting them together in one transaction.

I was looking at the `addBatch` method, but if I understand correctly it can be used with a single `PreparedStatement` to execute the same insert multiple times with different parameters, or be used on a `Statement` object to add more queries to the batch, but without the ability to add parameters (so I might be able to add the values in the sql string. SQL injection style).

I also tried a naive approach of writing both inserts in one sql statement (`insert into table1 values(?, ?); insert into table2 values(?, ?);`), but this way the `PreparedStatement` only sees the first two parameters, and trying to set the 3rd and 4th throws an exception.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your reason for not wanting to use two `PreparedStatement` in the same transaction?  That would make your life easier!

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is no special reason for not doing that, other than not thinking about it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can disable autocommit, execute two separate statements and then commit a transaction manually:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    ...
    stmt1.execute();
    ...
    stmt2.execute();
    connection.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    connection.rollback();
}
```

Comment: It is safe or a better practice to put the rollback inside a SQLException catch block ?