# Using batch insert on related tables in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, batch-insert

I have two MySQL tables, `Persons` and `Addresses`. In `Persons` table there is column `id_address` which is foreign key for `Addresses` column with same name. Column `id_address` in `Addresses` has `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed value. So when I want to insert new person, I insert address which sets `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to new value, then this last id I use for `Persons.id_address`.

So my question is, is there any option to set batch insert for these two tables, and then insert more rows in one step?

I'm using Java with MySQL driver and I need this without ORM framework.

**EDIT:** I found it's not possible, related answer is here:
[Two different prepared statements in one single batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977568/two-prepared-statements-in-one-batch)

Comment: may be defining a trigger would help?

Comment: I don't think so, I though about one commands with one PreparedStatement.execute(), but I found it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the SQL query is SIMPLE statement then both the queries can be executed in a batch.

**Here is an example**:

In col1 user specified value will be inserted and in col2 value returned by last_insert_id will be stored.

tbl2 has only one column which is auto-increment but you can have any no. of columns. The only restriction is this query has to be simple query (i.e. it CAN NOT be prepared statement).

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into tbl1 (col1, col2) (select ?, LAST_INSERT_ID());");
int i=0;
while(i < 2) {
   pStmt.setInt(1, 20);
   pStmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO tbl2 values();");
   pStmt.addBatch();
   i++;
}
pStmt.executeBatch();
```

This will first insert into **tbl2** followed by insert into **tbl1**.