# ExecuteUpdate sql statement in Java not working

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am learning how to use SQL with Java. I have installed the JDBC driver successfully and I am able to read the records from a database and print it on the screen.

My problem occurs when trying to do either an update or insert statement, where nothing happens. Here is my code:

**Method where the problem resides**

```
public static void updateSchools(ArrayList<String> newSchool)
{
    try
    {
        openDatabase();
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        int numberOfRows = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE schools SET address='abc' WHERE abbreviation='2';");
        System.out.println(numberOfRows);
        closeDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**Support functions**

```
public static void openDatabase()
{
    c = null;
    stmt = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Badminton", "postgres", "postgrespass");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Database opened successfully");
}

public static void closeDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Database closed successfully");
}
```

Here is an image of my very simple database:
[image]

The result in the console is the following, although no databases changes were done:

Database opened successfully

1

Database closed successfully

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use ";" it can breaks the sql; are you getting any exception ?

Comment: Mybe you need to refresh your db, or commit `c.setAutoCommit(True);`

Comment: @karelss From the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.4/static/install12418.htm): `Get in the habit of including those SQL semicolons`

Comment: Learn "try with resources".

Comment: try(Connection con = getConnection(url, username, password, "org.postgresql.Driver");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
) {

//statements
}catch(....){}                          Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove `c.setAutoCommit(false)` line from the `openDatabase` method.

Or

Add `c.commit()` at the end of the `updateSchool` method.

> After the auto-commit mode is disabled, no SQL statements are
>   committed until you call the method commit explicitly. All statements
>   executed after the previous call to the method commit are included in
>   the current transaction and committed together as a unit.

Comment: Thank you so much, my code now works as intended :).

Comment: An explanation why this solves the problem would add just that little extra to your answer.

Comment: My insert and update queries were not committed to the database, which is why I would not seen any changes. Once I added the commit line after my operations, the changes were done successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's query has been solved, but this might help someone.

It turns out that you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977744/9728769) execute two *different* Statements(or PreparedStatements) in a single batch.

I was having the same problem, no errors, no exceptions, the database record simply wouldn't update as it should.

Resusing the previously used PreparedStatement solved the problem.