# executeUpdate() is no working while execute using stored procedure

Tags: javascript, java, stored-procedures, oracle11g, execute

executeUpdate return 1 but values are not inserted into the table. 'CR_SAVEHBCRPERFORMA '   is the procedure to insert values. output parameter return 1 after execute else 0, here return 0..(some code missed bcoz too length
)

```
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt1 = null;
    DataSource ds = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
       
        String REGNO = request.getParameter("regNo");
        String CENTERNAME = request.getParameter("center");
        String DIAGNOSISDATE = request.getParameter("firstDiag");
        RccDataSources rccDS = new RccDataSources();
        ds = rccDS.getOncoLiveDS();
        con = ds.getConnection();
        cstmt1 = con.prepareCall("{CALL CR_SAVEHBCRPERFORMA(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        cstmt1.setString(1, REGNO);
        cstmt1.setString(2, CENTERNAME);
        cstmt1.setString(3, DIAGNOSISDATE);
        cstmt1.setString(4, SOURCEREG);
        cstmt1.setString(5, SOURCEREF);
        cstmt1.setString(6, LABNO); 
        cstmt1.setString(7, FIRSTSEENDATE);
        cstmt1.setString(8, EDUCATION);
        cstmt1.setString(28, TREATMENTRITYPE);
        cstmt1.setString(29, STATUSFOLLOWUP);
        cstmt1.setString(30, DISEASESTATUS);
        cstmt1.setString(31, REMARK);
        cstmt1.registerOutParameter(32, Types.INTEGER);
        cstmt1.executeUpdate();
        int x = cstmt1.getInt(32);
  
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you didn't commit? See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289951/executeupdate-sql-statement-in-java-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cstmt1.execute();
```

For Example

```
        stmt.setString(1, doc_number);
        stmt.setString(2, doc_type);
        stmt.setString(3, line_number);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(4, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        
        stmt.execute();
        cursor = stmt.getCursor(4);
```

Comment: ERROR:  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CR_SAVEHBCRPERFORMA' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: That error usually comes when you try to send wrong parameter value number instead of varchar.