# Update and select in single query . Sql syntax error in Scala

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, sql-update

I am trying to query the database using the below query. It works fine when I run the query in mysql server. But when I run the same query in scala it throws error.

I want to get a single row in db whose cid_status is "unreserved" and cid_curprocess is 'process1'and update the same cid_status to "reserved" and get back the cid_issueid of that row

Below is the query.

> val query = "SET @LastUpdateID := 0; UPDATE table_details INNER JOIN
>   (SELECT   cid_issueid FROM cen_issue_details WHERE
>   cid_curprocess='process1' AND cid_status='unreserved' LIMIT 1) AS
>   final ON cen_issue_details.cid_issueid=final.cid_issueid SET
>   cen_issue_details.cid_status ='reserved',cen_issue_details.cid_issueid
>   = (SELECT @LastUpdateID := cen_issue_details.cid_issueid);SELECT @LastUpdateID AS LastUpdateID;

```
val rs = statement.executeUpdate(query)
```

I get the below error:

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE table_details INNER JOIN (SELECT cid_issueid FROM cen_issue_details W' at line 1

Also I am not sure whether to use executeUpdate or executeQuery since the query does both SELECT and UPDATE.

Comment: What is confusing?  You are calling `executeupdate` with a string that has multiple statements.  That is not the write interface function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that. I was confused on how to execute multiple statements. I solved it using transaction. I wanted to know if there is any better approach.

Answer (score 1):

`Statement.executeupdate(String)` accepts only a single statement, but you have provided two.

See the docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

This question discusses the options for doing multiple statements in a single roundtrip with JDBC: [Two different prepared statements in one single batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977568/two-different-prepared-statements-in-one-single-batch)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using transaction solved my problem. I had to write 2 different queries and execute it.